# Application of Hund's third rule to rhodium

Tags: quantum-chemistry, electronic-configuration

The rhodium atom has electronic configuration: $[\ce{Kr}] \,\mathrm{4d^8\,5s^1}$; the atomic term symbol is $^4F$. The possible $j$-values are $9/2$, $7/2$, $5/2$ and $3/2$. However, when using Hund's third rule, in case of spin-orbit coupling (LS-coupling), there are multiple shells to look at. Which subshell (d or s) should I look at for the more than / less than half-filled rule? Or, if Hund's rule is not applicable, what should I do then to determine the levels? The correct answer is supposedly $9/2$, but could you give more explanation?

Comment: To clarify: the problem is not determining the levels, but the ground level. For this, the sign of the spin-orbit coupling parameter should be considered.

Comment: Another related question, but without answer: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/421616/how-to-use-hunds-third-rule-for-excited-electronic-configurations

Comment: For these kind of systems, the coupling between the $d$ electrons is much stronger than the coupling between the individual $d$ electrons with the single $s$ electron. You consider the $d^8$ part with LS coupling ($^3F_{4}$) as a parent term that is coupled to the $s^1$ ($^2S_{1/2}$) term. I don't think Hund's rules can be easily applied to find the value of $J$ for the ground state because of the interaction of the parent terms.

Comment: Cross posted here: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/691298/313612.

Comment: As a remark on @Paul's comment, I found the atomic term symbol by applying the vector model to the answer to both shells separately. The J-value was found by summing the separate ones (see http://www.quimica.ufpr.br/edulsa/cq115/leitura/Spectrocopic-Terms-1.pdf, last page). This only holds for LS-coupling.